# How to make the page script recognize a manually changed value of INPUT element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Chrome extension and am currently trying to get my content script to automatically do a search using the form on the site. I'm doing this by changing the value of the input and then using the jQuery `change()` method, since the site doesn't start searching otherwise.

```
var search = $("#videoSearchInput");
search.val("test");
search.change();
```

I've figured out that the `change()` method solves my problem by executing it through the Chrome console, but it doesn't work when I try to run it from my content script. I've found out that if I change the `"scope"(?)` of my console to that of my extension and then enter the command it doesn't change anything.

Is there some kind of extra permission this method requires?

And yes, I have jQuery working in my content script, as I'm changing the value of the input using the `val()` method.

Thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT:**
Maybe I should mention that the site uses AngularJS (which I'm very unfamiliar with) and that the input element has a bunch of attributes, but the only one that is being affected by the change() method is "ng-pristine".

Comment: Thank you very much, this works flawlessly and solves all my problems!

Comment: Good. I've posted it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say without seeing the actual page but it's possible the page checks if the input was "typed", which we can simulate by using [document.execCommand](http://devdocs.io/dom/document/execcommand):

```
document.getElementById('videoSearchInput').focus();
document.execCommand('selectAll');
document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'some text');
```

Or, if you use jQuery, register a new function:

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.execInsertText = function(text) {
        var activeElement = document.activeElement;
        var result = this.each(function() {
            this.focus();
            document.execCommand('selectAll');
            document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);
        });
        if (activeElement) {
            activeElement.focus();
        }
        return result;
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

then invoke it:

```
$("#videoSearchInput").execInsertText('herpderp');
```