# Simulating a keypress in a TamperMonkey script over facebook

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I'm trying to simulate a keypress to send a facebook message, the flow is to click the 'create new message' button, then paste (or fill) a recipients name, then press 'down' and 'enter' to choose the recipients from your friend list.
The page I'm looking at is https://www.facebook.com/messages/

```
function fillMessage(num){
        var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
        clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
        $("a[title='New Message']")[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);

    setTimeout(function() {
        var toInput = $('input[placeholder="Type the name of a person or group"]');

        toInput.val("Firstname Lastname");

        // jquery attempt
        toInput.trigger(jQuery.Event('keydown', {KeyCode: 71}));

        // javascript
        var e = new Event("keydown");
        e.keyCode = 71;
        toInput[0].dispatchEvent(e);
    }, 500);
}
```

The initial event to click a new message works, as well as filling the input with a persons name. However the following 'g' keypress doesn't.

The attempts here are a simplification, I've tried it dozens of ways, with event parameters, with or without 'grant unsafeWindow', with keydown/keyup/keypress.

Any tips?

Comment: Try [document.execCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42375168).

Comment: execCommand doesn't seem to have options to send a keystroke

Comment: That's interesting, I can simulate alphabetic keypresses that way, however do you know if it's possible to send other keystrokes with it? down arrow / enter / tab keys? (I imagine tab would lose the focus on the element, so that won't work for sure)

Comment: What I know is that modern browsers ignore js-originated keyboard and mouse events that, when issued by a real user activity, would trigger some native UI action like switching focus or expanding a select box and so on. Real events have `isTrusted: true` property.

Comment: basically what I need is to 'mimic the native browser' key events, there's a plugin that is supposed to do that https://github.com/jquery/jquery-simulate but I can't seem to get it to work