# How To Call Chrome Extension Function After Page Redirect?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am working on building a Javascript (in-browser) Instagram bot. However, I ran into a problem.

If you run this script, the first function will be called and the page will be redirected to "https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/samplehashtag/" and the second function will be called immediately after (on the previous URL before the page changes to the new URL). Is there a way to make the second function be called after this second URL has been loaded completely?

I have tried setting it to a Window setInterval() Method for an extended time period, window.onload and a couple of other methods. However, I can't seem to get anything to work. Any chance someone has a solution?

This is my first chrome extension and my first real project, so I may be missing something simple..

manifest.json

```
    {
  "name": "Inject Me",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Injecting stuff",
  "homepage_url": "http://danharper.me",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Inject!"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "https://*/*",
    "http://*/*",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

inject.js

```
  (function() {

  let findUrl = () => {
    let hashtag = "explore/tags/samplehashtag/";
    location.replace("https://www.instagram.com/" + hashtag);
  }

  findUrl();
})();
```

background.js

```
    // this is the background code...

// listen for our browerAction to be clicked
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  // for the current tab, inject the "inject.js" file & execute it
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib, {
    file: 'inject.js'
  });

});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {

  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib, {
    file: 'inject2.js'
  });


});
```

inject2.js

```
(function() {

if (window.location.href.indexOf("https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/samplehashtag/") != -1){
  let likeAndRepeat = () => {
    let counter = 0;
    let grabPhoto = document.querySelector('._9AhH0');

    grabPhoto.click();

    let likeAndSkip = function() {
      let heart = document.querySelector('.glyphsSpriteHeart__outline__24__grey_9.u-__7');
      let arrow = document.querySelector('a.coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow');

      if (heart) {
        heart.click();
        counter++;
        console.log(`You have liked ${counter} photographs`)
      }
      arrow.click();
    }

    setInterval(likeAndSkip, 3000);
    //alert('likeAndRepeat Inserted');
  };

  likeAndRepeat();

}
})();
```

Comment: When your script redirects to the new URL, the current instance of the content script gets destroyed along with the old page on the old URL. That's because your `hashtag` isn't a hashtag but just a URL path. I guess you should click the link in the page using element.click() so that the page navigates itself using History API, then you do a pause via setTimeout or wait for the new contents using MutationObserver, and finally click the like button.

Comment: The problem I had with using element.click is that there is actually no "submit" button for the search field. It loads as you type. So injecting a string into the search bar cannot actually cause the search form to pull results. At least in no way that I tried.

Comment: You can simulate user typing with document.execCommand, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42375168).

Comment: Thats interesting.. Could you potentially provide an example of how you would do that?? Might make my solution a lot cleaner.. The search bar would be on instagram.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear from the question and the example, when you want to run your function. But in chrome extension there is something called **Message Passing**

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

With message passing you can pass messages from one file to another, and similarly listen for messages.
So as it looks from your use case, you can listen for a particular message and then fire your method.

For example

```
background.js

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({message: "FIRE_SOME_METHOD"})


popup.js

    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request) {

    if (request.message == "FIRE_SOME_METHOD")
      someMethod();
  });
```

**EDIT**
Also if you want to listen for the URL changes, you can simply put a listener provided as in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated).

```
  chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
      console.log('updated tab');
  });
```

Comment: Sorry that I was unclear.. I essentially want to call the likeAndRepeat function once my findUrl function is called and the new URL (in this case "instagram.com/explore/tags/samplehashtag" is loaded completely. I don't think passing this off to another js file will solve this problem.. Maybe I am just not looking at this the right way?

Comment: I updated my answer so hopefully it is a bit more clear what I am trying to do :)

Comment: I have updated my answer as well, please check and try if it solves your problem.

Comment: Hmm.. still doesn't seem to be working. Seems like its definitely on the right track. I am supposed to put this in my background.js file, right?

Comment: Yes, you can put this in your background.js file.

Comment: I updated my answer to include what I have now.. Unfortunately still not working though.

Comment: Can you tell me where are you checking the console.log for the listener ? Also it will just log "updated tab" when your tab changes, there is nothing functional in there.

Comment: You should open chrome://extensions and then in your extension card, click on the background page. Then the opened devtools you will be able to check console logs from background.js file.

Comment: My apologies, I was checking the console of the current page, not in chrome://extensions. I am still not 100% sure how I can implement this yet, but I am miles ahead of where I was. Thanks so much for your time! I am sure I can figure it out from here.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I have updated my code to the correct answer in case anyone is interested. It definitely isn't very clean yet, but it works. I appreciate your guidance!